# Unable to bypass the "Pick user popup" after Sign Out in a Blazor WASM application

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I have written a .Net 8 Blazor WASM application that uses Azure/Entra ID for authentication.  We need to execute an automatic sign out when the user has been idle and bypass the "Pick user popup" after sign out.

Here is my Program.cs code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using THDVirtualAgent;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    // Redirect to home page after login failure
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInFailedPath = "/?loginFailed=true"; 
    // Redirect to home page after logout
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogOutSucceededPath = "/";
});

var assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Here is the method called when the idle timer expires:

```
[JSInvokable]
public Task HandleInactivityAsync()
  {
      //Set the sign out state using the SignOutSessionStateManager
      SignOutManager.SetSignOutState();

      // Currently not used, but could be used to extract the login hint from the user's claims
      var loginHint = ExtractLoginHintFromClaims();
           
      //Navigate to the logout page
      NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/logout");
        
      return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
```

I've enabled the login_hint optional claim in my apps registration in Azure/Entra ID. This is the section from my app manifest:

```
    "optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "login_hint",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
    ],
    "accessToken": [],
    "saml2Token": []
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To hopefully help point you in the right direction when it comes to modifying your Blazor application's code to include the `login_hint` parameter and bypass the "Pick user popup" after sign-out, you should be able to reference the below.

For more info - [How to Logout of an OAuth2 Application without getting prompted to seelct a user.](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2022/03/how-to-logout-of-an-oauth2-application-without-getting-prompted-to-select-a-user/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20logout%20of%20an%20OAuth2%20application%20without,logout_hint%20parameter%20where%20login_hint%20is%20the%20value%3A%20)

```
// Construct the logout URL with the logout_hint and post_logout_redirect_uri parameters 

var logoutUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={logoutRedirectUri}&logout_hint={userId}"; 

var logoutUrl = $"authentication/logout?login_hint={userId}&post_logout_redirect_uri={logoutRedirectUri}&prompt=none";


//Open ID Connect/OAuth2 application example:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&logout_hint={user_id}
```

Additional Link:

- [Send a sign-out request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request)

I hope this helps!